# Exact expression for a bond Probablity

Tags: integration

I am currently reading Modern Theory of Polymer solutions and have gotten stuck on a derivation. One pages 10-11 [(here)](http://www.molsci.polym.kyoto-u.ac.jp/archives/redbook.pdf), we start with the characteristic function for long chain polymer, where all bond probabilities are assumed to be the same, in spherical coordinates.

$K(\boldsymbol{p}) = [\int \tau(\boldsymbol{r} * exp(i \boldsymbol{p\cdot \boldsymbol{r}}))d\boldsymbol{r}]^n$

where $\tau$ is given by

1)  $\tau(\boldsymbol{r}) = (4\pi a^2)^{-1}\delta(|\boldsymbol{r}| - a )$

(assuming the each bond is of a constant length)

On the next page, the solution is given as

2) $K(\bf{p}) = \frac{sin(ap)}{ap}^n$

Needless to say, I haven't gotten this answer.

Attempt:

Plugging 2 into 1 yields :

$(4\pi a^2)^{-1} \int \delta(|\boldsymbol{r}| -a) exp(i\boldsymbol{p}\cdot\boldsymbol r) d\boldsymbol{r} $

because our system is spherically symmetric, we can set the direction of 
$\boldsymbol{\rho}$ to the z axis. This allows us to rewrite the dot product as

$(4\pi a^2)^{-1} \int \delta(|\boldsymbol{r}| -a) exp^{(i|\boldsymbol{p}||\boldsymbol r| cos\theta)} d\boldsymbol{r} $

We can then expand our integration element $d\boldsymbol{r}$ into $r^2 sin\theta d\theta d\phi$.

$(4\pi a^2)^{-1} \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{\inf} \delta(|\boldsymbol{r}| -a) exp^{(i|\boldsymbol{p}||\boldsymbol r|cos\theta)} r^2 sin\theta dr d\theta d\phi $

The $\phi $ integral is trivial (at least I think) and I used a u sub to do the $\theta$ integral (which left me with two terms ). Finally I could do the r integral (which in turn left me with four).

If anyone could give me any insight as to how to proceed or solve this, I would appreciate it greatly! Thank you for your time.

P.S. This is my first time posting, so I apologize if I formatted poorly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out thanks to Chinny84's answer.

So starting with:

$(4πa^2)^{−1}∫_0^{2\pi}∫_0^{\pi}∫_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\inf} δ(|r|−a)exp^{(i|p||r|cosθ)}r^2sinθdrdθdϕ$

The phi derivative is trivial, yielding a factor of $2\pi$.
$(2a^2)^{−1}∫_0^{\pi}\int_0^{\inf} δ(|r|−a)exp^{(i|p||r|cosθ)}r^2sinθdrdθ$

Next comes the $\theta$ derivative, which can be accomplished by a u-sub.

$u = cos \theta$

$du =-sin\theta$

which allows us to write:
$\int_{-1}^1 e^{(ipr u)}du  = \frac{e^{(ipr)} - e^{(-ipr)}}{ipr}$

The exponential can be rewritten as a sin term:

$2i sin(pr)$

when everything is plugged in, we get:

$(pa^2)^{(-1)}\int_0^{\inf} \delta(|\boldsymbol{r}|-a)|\boldsymbol{r}|  sin(|\boldsymbol{r}|\rho) dr$

Taking advantage of the delta function our integral becomes

$a sin(ap)$

plugging in yields the final answer:

$\frac{sin(ap)}{ap}$

which is raised to the nth power.

In my original attempt, I took the r integral before using the delta function's property, which is wrong. That, and I forgot that the $e^x - e^{-x}$ term can be rewritten as a sine.

Answer (score 0):

Note this is a partial answer - until proven otherwise.
$$
K(\vec{\rho}) = (4\pi a^2)^{-n}\left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty\tau(\vec{r})\mathrm{e}^{i\vec{\rho} \cdot\vec{r}}d\vec{r}\right]^n 
$$
Concentrating on the integral we find
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(|\vec{r}|-a)\mathrm{e}^{i\vec{\rho} \cdot\vec{r}}d\vec{r}
$$
we can split the domain
$$
\int_{0}^\infty\delta(\vec{r}-a)\mathrm{e}^{i\vec{\rho} \cdot\vec{r}}d\vec{r} + \int_{-\infty}^0\delta(\vec{r}-a)\mathrm{e}^{i\vec{\rho} \cdot\vec{r}}d\vec{r} = \int_{0}^\infty\delta(\vec{r}-a)\mathrm{e}^{i\vec{\rho} \cdot\vec{r}}d\vec{r} -\int_{0}^\infty\delta(\vec{r}-a)\mathrm{e}^{-i\vec{\rho} \cdot\vec{r}}d\vec{r}
$$
now using the property of the delta function namely
$$
\int_{\Omega} \delta(x-a)f(x)dx = f(a) \iff a \in \Omega
$$
$$
\int_{0}^\infty\delta(\vec{r}-a)\mathrm{e}^{i\vec{\rho} \cdot\vec{r}}d\vec{r} -\int_{0}^\infty\delta(\vec{r}-a)\mathrm{e}^{-i\vec{\rho} \cdot\vec{r}}d\vec{r} = \mathrm{e}^{i\vec{\rho}\cdot a}  -\mathrm{e}^{-i\vec{\rho}\cdot a} = 2i\sin(\vec{p}\cdot a)
$$

So I get
$$
K(\vec{\rho}) = \left[\frac{2i\sin(\vec{\rho}\cdot \vec{a})}{4\pi a^2}\right]^n = \left[\frac{i\sin(\vec{\rho}\cdot \vec{a})}{2\pi a^2}\right]^n = \left[\frac{i|\vec{\rho}|}{2\pi^2|\vec{a}|}\right]^n\left[\frac{\sin(\vec{\rho}\cdot \vec{a})}{|\vec{a}||\vec{\rho}|}\right]^n
$$